# Node post-installation failure - 'cloudinit' running config-apt-configure with frequency once-per-instance

Tags: maas

Server with MAAS 2.3 installed where the nodes can be commissioned without problems. However, when deploying an ubuntu image I got the following errors.

**MAAS GUI:**

***Nodes -> Events***

```
Node post-installation failure - 'cloudinit' running modules for config
Node post-installation failure - 'cloudinit' running config-apt-configure with frequency once-per-instance
```

I can login into the nodes, install package without errors, ping and traceroute other DNS servers.

**Node**

***Command:***

> sudo cloud-init status --long status:

```
> error time: Thu, 21 Jun 2018
> 19:39:41 +0000 detail: ('apt-configure', ValueError('Old and New apt
> format defined with unequal values True vs False @
> apt_preserve_sources_list',))
```

***file:*** **cloud-init.log**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/stages.py", line 792, in _run_modules
    freq=freq)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cloud.py", line 54, in run
    return self._runners.run(name, functor, args, freq, clear_on_fail)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/helpers.py", line 187, in run
    results = functor(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_apt_configure.py", line 274, in handle
    ocfg = convert_to_v3_apt_format(ocfg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_apt_configure.py", line 759, in convert_to_v3_apt_format
    cfg = convert_v2_to_v3_apt_format(cfg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_apt_configure.py", line 725, in convert_v2_to_v3_apt_format
    oldkey))
ValueError: Old and New apt format defined with unequal values True vs False @ apt_preserve_sources_list
```

I have tried different approach to solve the problem without success.

I don't know what is wrong. Any help is more than welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link provides the solution:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1735950/comments/12